# List of selected items in expendable list checkbox

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want to fetch the selected data item from expendable listview. First I got all the elements whether i selected them or not... but i am not able to get the selected items. and display these as parents with its childs.

```
public class CategoryBaseAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context _context;
private List<ProfessionEntity> _listDataHeader;
public static HashMap<ProfessionEntity, List<ProfessionChildEntity>> _listDataChild;
public static HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> mChildCheckStates;
    private Map<ProfessionEntity, List<ProfessionChildEntity>> selectedItems;
public CategoryBaseAdapter(Context context,
        List<ProfessionEntity> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<ProfessionEntity, List<ProfessionChildEntity>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    selectedItems = new HashMap<ProfessionEntity,List<ProfessionChildEntity>>();
}
public Map<ProfessionEntity, List<ProfessionChildEntity>> getSelectedItems() {
    return selectedItems;
}
public boolean isSelected(int groupPosition, int childPosition){
    ProfessionEntity group = _listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    ProfessionChildEntity child = getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
    List<ProfessionChildEntity> sel = selectedItems.get(group);
    return sel != null && sel.contains(child);
}
public void toggleSelection(int groupPosition, int childPosition){
    ProfessionEntity group = _listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    ProfessionChildEntity child = getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);

    List<ProfessionChildEntity> sel = selectedItems.get(group);
    if (sel == null){
        sel = new ArrayList<ProfessionChildEntity>();
        selectedItems.put(group, sel);
    }

    if (sel.contains(child))
        sel.remove(child);
    else
        sel.add(child);

}

@Override
public ProfessionChildEntity getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    final int mChildPosition = childPosition;
    final String childText = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)
            .getDescription();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);

    }
    final CheckBox childCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.childCheckBox);
    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.childTextView);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    childCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);         
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public ProfessionEntity getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = getGroup(groupPosition).getDecription();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
    }
    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.groupTextView);
    CheckBox grpCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.groupCheckBox);
    grpCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d("grp clicked", "grpCheckBox");
        }
    });
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    grpCheckBox.setTag(convertView);
    if (isExpanded) {
        Log.d("abc", "abc");
    } else {
        Log.d("abc", "abc");
    }
    return convertView;
}
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: You have to use the HashMap with consists its parent value and  the value which are selected in child

Comment: how to mange random selections

Comment: With respect to parent of selected item...you have to manage that...In the getChildView method ...you have to make the onclick listener and manage it

Comment: not clear what problem you getting .

Comment: simply how to get the selected item of parents and child... here i mselecting but not getting those @Pavan

Comment: thanx @RavindraKushwaha let me try this

Comment: did you want only that items are selected via checkbox if it is , then you can maintain one boolean field in your adapter dataset and change its value in checkbox setOnCheckedChangeListener and notify the adapter then you can easily get the selected item filtered from main dataset

Comment: @AmitaJain ...Do you want to muliple selection of child item or single item selection of particular parent??

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha i have multiple selection of child as there i put check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

In `getGroupView()` method you should try this :

```
    @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GroupHolder groupHolder;
            String headerTitle = getGroup(groupPosition).getDecription();
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
                groupHolder = new GroupHolder();
                 groupHolder.lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.groupTextView);
                groupHolder.grpCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.groupCheckBox);
        convertView.setTag(groupHolder);
            }
        else
        {
        groupHolder = (GroupHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

         groupHolder.grpCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    new onCheckBoxClick() 
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void OnCheckClick(boolean isChecked) 
                        {
                            groupHolder.grpCheckBox.setChecked(isChecked);
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
           groupHolder.lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
// you can get data from your modal class i.e.ProfessionEntity class which you have to show check box checked or not checked the following line is for your understanding.           
groupHolder.grpCheckBox.setChecked(groupHolder.grpCheckBox.getChecked());    

            return convertView;
        }

        private class GroupHolder
        {
                TextView lblListHeader
                CheckBox grpCheckBox;

        }

        private interface onCheckBoxClick
        {
                void OnCheckClick(boolean isChecked);
        }
```

If you have any question let me know

Comment: i am getting trouble in fetching the child selected items

Comment: I am getting trouble in fetching the child selected items ... there one conditon in code if(isexpand) that lg value is printed in logcat but how if i want to fetch the child selected values

Comment: if you want to show checked that `grpCheckBox` then you want to implement boolean value in your modal class that I already write in comment above of `groupHolder.grpCheckBox.setChecked(groupHolder.grpCheckBox.getChecked());` in code. but till you have any question then please post your ProfessionEntity class code otherwise I will share one demo application project, also let me know if you have any question